# How do I create custom layouts for Panelizer?

Tags: 8, panels, layout-builder

I was wondering how do you create custom layouts for Panelizer in D8? In D7, I can easily create my layouts, and just add a couple of lines on my .info file to let Drupal know where my layouts are.

I created a custom module following a "How to create custom layouts using Layout Builder tutorial". Can I just change the dependencies in the info.yml file that's inside my custom layout module like this:

```
name: 'Custom Layout'
type: module
description: 'Provides a way for layout'
core: 8.x
package: 'Custom'
dependencies:
  - panelizer:panelizer
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Panelizer is based on Panels module, which uses Layout API module in Drupal Core for providing  layout plugins. Please refer to the relevant documentation:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/layout-api/how-to-register-layouts is written with newer Layout Builder in mind, but basics should be the same
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2578731 is an older version of the same docs - might be slightly out of date, but also contain something not present in the previous document

Comment: Got it, thank you!